# wrong output for simple program

Tags: c++

I started to code a really simple task but I keep getting the wrong output. Help me, I'm desperate!
The problem is: I have to print a table 4*10. The numbers in the table go from 1 to 40 and they are ascending- the table looks like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

My task is to replace the every other multiple of 3 ( 3, 9, 15) is  by the number 2. Every multiple of 5 that hasn't already been used is replaced by the number 3. Everything else is replaced by 1.

```
 #include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>


using namespace std;

    int table[10][4];
    int i,j;
    int br;

int main()
{
    br=1;


    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {

    if(br%6==3) table[i][j]=2;
    else if(br%5==0 && br%6!=3) table[i][j]=3;
    else table[i][j]=1;


    br++;
    }


    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
    printf("%d",table[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }



return 0;
}
```

The output I keep getting : 
1121111121
1111211111
2111112131
1121311123

The output I should get:
1121311123
1111211113
2111312113
1121311123

Comment: Enable all warnings and debugging options (e.g. compile with `g++ -Wall -g`) and use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: "that hasn't already been used"?

Comment: anyway, note that the table-ness is a property of the *presentation* only, and that your logic only needs to deal with the sequence of consecutive integers starting with 1 and ending with 40.

Comment: For example, 15 is replaced by 2 (it is a multiple of 3), and therefore should not be replaced by 3, although it is the multiple of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are using your indices backwards with respect to how you declared your array:

```
int table[10][4];

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
   if(br%6==3) table[i][j]=2;
   else if(br%5==0 && br%6!=3) table[i][j]=3;
   else table[i][j]=1;
```

See how your (i) variable in the for loop is set to go 0,1,2,3 and your (j) variable in the inner loop is set to go (0,1,2,3,...,9) ?  Then you set items in your array using table[i][j], which means that you'll be setting table[0][0] through table[3][9], but your table is declared as table[10][4].

The solution would be either to change your table declaration to be table[4][10], or alternatively change your instances of table[i][j] to be table[j][i] instead.  Either way will work, as long as your for-loop ranges match your table's dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You access the array in the wrong order. Instead of

```
table[i][j];
```

you should write

```
table[j][i];
```

whenever accessing your table as `i` denotes your row and `j` your column (as long as you name them consistently).

Alternatively swap the indexing in the table declaration, i.e.

```
int table[4][10];
```

instead of

```
int table[10][4];
```

[The output is then correct.](http://ideone.com/82eJyb)

Comment: Or simply define the array as `int table[4][10];` instead.